# Bin the date into month

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime, python-dateutil

Now I have a table:

```
Score  Customer ID      my_dates        Threshold Model_name   is_alert
50         8           2017-08-05         50     Mod1          yes
50         9           2017-12-05         50     Mod1          yes
50         28          2017-05-22         50     Mod2          yes
50         28          2017-05-26         50     Mod2          yes
50         36          2017-06-20         50     Mod2          yes
```

If the score equal or exceed the threshold, is_alert will show 'yes'

Now I want to bin the date into the following formate and print how many alerts in each bin under each model but if within 7 days for one customer is alerted more than once, only the first hit contributes to the total score:

```
Model_name   Jan-17    Feb-17    Mar-17    APR-17   May-17   Jun-17 
Mod1                                                           
Mod2
```

Can somebody help me with that? Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code you have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with convert datetimes to month periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html), last convert to names of months by [`PeriodIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.strftime.html), but before get difference per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) and filter rows with missing values (first rows per groups) and less or equal like `7` by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['my_dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['my_dates'])

m = df['my_dates'].dt.to_period('m')
df['diff'] = df.groupby(['Model_name'])['my_dates'].diff().dt.days
print (df)
   Score  Customer ID   my_dates  Threshold Model_name is_alert   diff
0     50            8 2017-08-05         50       Mod1      yes    NaN
1     50            9 2017-12-05         50       Mod1      yes  122.0
2     50           28 2017-05-22         50       Mod2      yes    NaN
3     50           28 2017-05-26         50       Mod2      yes    4.0
4     50           36 2017-06-20         50       Mod2      yes   25.0

df = df[df['diff'].ge(7) | df['diff'].isna()]
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['Model_name'], m)
df1.columns = df1.columns.strftime('%b-%y')
print (df1)
my_dates    May-17  Jun-17  Aug-17  Dec-17
Model_name                                
Mod1             0       0       1       1
Mod2             1       1       0       0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I also need to check whether the two dates are within 7 days, so the Mod2 under May-17 should be 1. I'm not sure how to do that?